# Support diffent Blackberry OS versions with differing functionality from the same COD file

Tags: java, blackberry, versioning, dynamic-linking

I would like to support BlackBerry OS versions representing more than 90% of installed user base. Right now that means supporting OS versions 4.5 through 6.0.

I need to have touch-and-swipe events on models supporting with a touch screen, and I would like the same binary to load on both OS 4.5 and higher OS versions.

Is this possible? When I add a method `TouchEvent` to the code, the application no longer loads on my 8800, OS version 4.5.

Coming from the Windows and Linux PC world it feels odd to be so limited. On these bigger platforms you can create an app that works on any OS version and gracefully drops features not supported on an older platform.

I think I want dynamic class loading, but I am not sure.

What I have found related so far:
["is it possible to have a single build i.e cod file for touch and non-touch screen."](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Preprocessor-not-working-in-4-5/m-p/548808/highlight/true)
The end of that thread is ["It isn't possible to do what you would like"](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Preprocessor-not-working-in-4-5/td-p/548522/highlight/true/page/2) Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is having one COD file a requirement?   RIM provides support for a preprocessor, and the idea is that you can conditionally compile code, depending on your target OS.

The app I have experience with uses browser agent sniffing to offer the appropriate COD file to BlackBerry users.   AppWorld also allows you to submit multiple COD files for one application, where each one is tailored for a specific OS version.   AppWorld provides the right one to users when they download your app.

Comment: It would have been nice to have only one COD, but we will go for the browser agent thing. Thanks!